# angular $interval index start from 1 after upgrading library to 1.6.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing strange issue after upgrading library to 1.6.1

**version 1.4.8**

```
//items.length is 3
this.$interval((index)=> {console.log(index)   // output started from 0
                                if (index > 2) {console.log(index)
                                    thisObj.$interval.cancel(int);
                                }
                                else {
                                    thisObj.lastThreeTransactions.push(items[index]);
                                }
                            }, 100, items.length);
```

**version 1.6.1**

```
console.log(index)   // output started from 1
```

Due to that only two item getting pushed to new array. The 0 th index value not getting pushed in version 1.6.1

Is someone else facing the same issue, Is it some kind of bug or is there any solution. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the full controller code, whose part is this snippet.

Comment: The change seems to have come with 1.5. But before 1.5.10 the documentation does not even explicitly state that anything is passed.